# Should I run my unit tests against the Rollup bundle?

Tags: node.js, typescript, unit-testing, rollup

What is the best approach for Jest testing a Typescript library I built, i.e.
import `*.ts` source code files, or the generated Rollup bundle files (CJS, ESM)?
In the latter case, is it advisable to code tests in Typescript?